# i want to retain the value of radio button when open and close the modal in Ionic2 using modalcontroller

Tags: ionic2, radio-group

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';


import { FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from "../tabs/tabs"
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'listing.html'
})

export class ListingPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Dashboard');
  }
  //modals started
  filterSort() {

     let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SortModal);
    modal.present();
  }

}
@Component({
  selector:"sort-page",
  templateUrl:"filter/sort.listing.filter.html",
  providers:[ListingPage]
})
export class SortModal {
  relationship:string;
  filtersStore:Array<string>=[];
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _filterservice:FilterModalsService,private _v:ViewController,private _sharedservice: SharedService,private listingpage:ListingPage,public navCtrl: NavController){
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        langs: new FormControl()
      })

  }
   doSubmit() {
    this.listingpage.onSearch(0,true);
    this._v.dismiss();
  }

   reset(){
    this.myForm.reset();
    this._sharedservice.deleteData();
  }
}
```

`listingpage` is parent component in which i open the `SortModal` component as modal in ionic 2 and child is `SortModal` but when i open the modal by defualt every element is reset and then i select one from the list and dismiss the modal but when i open the modal again all value again empty.  i want retain value the element of radio which i selected before

Comment: Perhaps create the modal in ionViewDidLoad and present it in your click function.

Comment: can you explain me ? how? now i created seprate function for modal .   ionViewDidLoad() {
    
     this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SortModal);
  }
  //modals started
  filterSort() {
   this.modal.present();
  }

Comment: Put 'let modal = modalCtr.create' in your ionViewDidLoad

Comment: yeah done but does not work, i hv updated  my comment